# "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"&"Attribute tools:context is not allowed here"

Tags: android

my android studio is displaying two sets of errors ("URL is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schema and DTD)" & "Attribute tools:context is not allowed here") and has been unable to build.What do i do?

i started the android class barely a week ago and i was asked to update the IDE & Pluggin, which i did. downloaded all the sdk tools.

this code is on my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width ="match_parent"
android:layout_height ="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World!"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so far its still trying to build....."waiting for build to finish..."